# C++ Recursion - adding tree data to list in order

Tags: c++, list, recursion

My code is below - I'm trying to return to my main a list of aircrafts that I'm getting from a binary tree in order (smallesty to largest). For the code below, I get the root node twice. I've been working on it for hours... any suggestions?

Thanks,
Charlotte

```
std::list<Aircraft> Tree::buildList()
{
    std::list<Aircraft> aircraftList;
    if (_root != 0)
    {
        aircraftList = buildListHelp(_root, aircraftList);
        aircraftList.push_front(*_root->getAircraftData());     
    }
    return aircraftList;
}

std::list<Aircraft> Tree::buildListHelp(Node* node, std::list<Aircraft> aircraftList)
{
    //aircraftList.push_back(*node->getAircraftData())
    /*if (node->getLeft() != 0)
    {*/
    if (node==0)
        return aircraftList;
    buildListHelp(node->getLeft(), aircraftList);
    //}
    aircraftList.push_back(*node->getAircraftData());
    /*if (node->getRight() != 0)
    {*/
    buildListHelp(node->getRight(), aircraftList);  
    //}
    return aircraftList;
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through it in a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming _root is declared as

```
Node* _root;
```

You are pushing it twice:

```
aircraftList.push_front(*_root->getAircraftData());    
aircraftList.push_back(*node->getAircraftData());
```

In first call of buildListHelp